# Union query to subtract totals

Tags: sql

Needing to subtract the total of credit memos from the total of invoices for accounts in a given date range.

I've tried a few nested/subqueries (most of my sql is self taught and subpar at best) but nothing has worked the way i expect it to.

```
Select 

(
(SELECT SUM(T1.Doctotal)
FROM
OINV T1 
WHERE 
T1.[DocDate] >=[%0] AND T1.[DocDate] <=[%1]
)

 -

(SELECT SUM(T2.Doctotal)
FROM
ORIN T2
WHERE
T2.[DocDate] >=[%0] AND T2.[DocDate] <=[%1]
)
) as 'balance'

from

(
(Select t3.CardName as 'cardname', t3.DocTotal as 'Doctotal'
from oinv t3
where
T3.[DocDate] >=[%0] AND T3.[DocDate] <=[%1])

union all

(Select t4.cardname as 'cardname', t4.doctotal as 'doctotal'
from orin t4 
where
T4.[DocDate] >=[%0] AND T4.[DocDate] <=[%1])) as x
```

Im trying to achieve a table where i have the

CardName, Invoice Total, Credit Memo Total, Invoice - credit memo total

or even just

CardName, Invoice -CM Total

Comment: Share sample input and desired output. Union doesnt perform add/subtract/etc operations on data but just combine rows with same no of columns and types and did you run those inner queries seperately as I could see ` <='%1' ` is it working

Comment: Is it OpenSQL or what? From the code I assume no. Add necessary tags to define target SQL dialect